# Find a bijective function between two segments of R

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In my homework in set theory i was asked to find a bijective function between (a,b) and (c,d) that are subsets of R. d>c and b>a.

I'm having problems thinking of a function that is surjective and injective.
i thought of the function for example f(x) = x+d-b, where x is an element in (a,b) and it is indeed injective, but not surjective...

I can use some advice please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $$(b-a)\cdot\dfrac{d-c}{b-a} = d-c.$$

Comment: I don't understand how this helps. I mean, yeah it's true what you wrote but I don't know how to use this to solve the question

Comment: The problem with your proposed "solution" was that the lengths of the intervals were not equal. Hence you must use this proportionality factor.